# Documenting LUNs/CIFs Shares/NFS Mounts

Tags: netapp

I have been tasked with standing up a new NetApp FAS 9000 and moving off our older 8040. I've done a few things within OnTap before and troubleshot a couple problems when the primary person was out of town, but I haven't done much more than that. I want to start by documenting the existing LUNs/CIFS shares and NFS mounts being used on the current 8040. Is there an easier way to do this rather than manually copying paths and names and such? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetApp's Powershell Toolkit helped achieve this. Build scripts around Get-NcLun, Get-NcCifsShare, and Get-NcVol.